# How to create a python script that checks if a given point is inside a certain area?

Tags: python, coordinates

I want to make a python script which checks this, but the point i will be using are (for example) x = 1290 to 1340 and y = 1460 to 1510 (this means that A = 1290 B = 1340 C = 1460 and D = 1510), i have already made a simple script but it needs me to write every single possible coordinate mannualy... here it is:

```
print ("")
print ("1923 1682")
print ("")
print ("Click below here to type!")

NFGCOORDINATES = (//here every single possible coordinate will come)
guess = str(input())

if guess in NFGCOORDINATES:
        print ("Coordinates are in NFG area")
        print ("")
        print ("Made by El_Capitano with love!")
else:
        print ("Coordinates are NOT in NFG area")
        print ("")
        print ("Made by El_Capitano with love!")
```

Anyone has tips to make this either easier or make a total different script?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is your area a polygon? Is it convex or can it be arbitrary? Please provide some example input of what `NFGCOORDINATES` looks like.

Comment: My area is a 2D square with 4 points, A B C and D, example of input is x: 1298 y: 1471, thats and example input an user will use (Btw thanks for response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the sides of the square are parallel to the coordinate axis, you just have to check if the `x` input is between the limits and that the `y` input is between the limits. Also, assuming the limits are inclusive (i.e. `x == 1290` is inside the square).  Thus:

```py
print('Your input should be of the form: 1923 1682')
guess = input()
try:
    x, y = [int(val) for val in guess.split()]
except:   # This is a very crude check.
    print('Wrong input format')
    raise

# Limits of the rectangle
x_low = 1290
x_high = 1340
y_low = 1460
y_high = 1510

if (x_low <= x <= x_high) and (y_low <= y <= y_high):
        print ("Coordinates are in NFG area")
else:
        print ("Coordinates are NOT in NFG area")
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks mate, fixed it :)

Comment: Although, do you have an idea on how to add multiple points? So i make every rectangle in an seperate section and it checks every sections?